# SQL date and time query not importing all

Tags: sql-server, mysql, query

I have the below table and when i run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Date <= "11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM"
```

it only retrieves the dates 15,14,13,12,11,10 and 1 of Nov 2018 .
How can i solve this? Thanks!

I tried changing the format of the date in the `WHERE` part of the query to `"11/15/18 12:00:00 AM"`, it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or MySQL? They're different.

Comment: @LowlyDBA To be honest, i don't know, but it's the same sql that i type in Microsoft Access queries, if that helps.

Comment: You will need to ask the owner of the database then what the expected dataset should be. Your results are all less than or equal to that date, so unless you are missing rows, this is working as expected.

Comment: Please be very careful to use unambiguous date/time formats. Both SQL Server and humans can misconstrue `11/12/18` as December 11th or November 12th under various circumstances. `20181112` is unambiguous and language-safe.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for your note :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case where the date column isn't a date at all, but rather a string.

You aren't getting Nov 2 through Nov 9 because the sorting on the *string* and calculating if it's less than `11/1....` in *alphanumeric* order.

Ideally, dates will be stored as dates, and then your existing query will work. This will also ensure that dates are valid dates, and you don't end up with data for 32 February, or even random strings.

If you can't change the type of the column, you'll have to cast the database values to a date to do the comparison (which will hurt performance, but get you the results you expect).

Comment: You, sir, are a very smart person. The operation i want to do is on a much bigger database, something like 18 columns and 1 million rows and i have imported it into Microsoft Access as a text file, but i provided this small two column example to simplify matters. My bad, i should have mentioned importing it as strings. Now i know why it doesn't work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not honor `AM`.

MySQL wants dates to be specified `Year/month/day`.

You can *format* output to be `dd/mm/yy` if you like, using `DATE_FORMAT`, but do *not* expect anything to recognize that ordering.